# Umbraco 5 setup. Access to the path is denied

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, permissions, umbraco

I use Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.0.
I downloaded umbraco5 sources, created new site in IIS, set physical path to path to umbraco sources, edited permissions for IIS_IUSRS and NETWORK SERVICE. Then I installed umbraco, set admin's login and password. After it I added sources to new MVC3 project in VS2010 and set up web properties of the project to use IIS server (http://localhost:5050).

When I try to run project I get error: "Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\57060572\e5101f9c\Umbraco.Cms.Web.Editors.dll' is denied."

I checked event viewer log, so here it is:

Event code: 4011 
Event message: An unhandled access exception has occurred. 
Event time: 20.03.2012 13:05:33 
Event time (UTC): 20.03.2012 9:05:33 
Event ID: f21a6458d0844eb08296e8e1e0c7d351 
Event sequence: 1 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0

Application information:

```
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT-9-129767079319772708 
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: / 
Application Path: D:\asitnikov\tfs\HospitalSite\Sources\HospitalSite\HospitalSite\ 
Machine name: PC4
```

Process information:

```
Process ID: 5752 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: IIS APPPOOL\HospitalSite
```

Request information:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:5050/ 
Request path: / 
User host address: ::1 
User:  
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type:  
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\HospitalSite
```

I've edited permissions for 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319' folder and given full control to IIS_IUSRS, NETWORK SERVICE and IIS APPPOOL\HospitalSite but I see no effect.
Also, I have two logical disks on pc and when I make all these operations on disk "C" I don't run into this problem but only locating of project on disk "D" causes a trouble.

**EDIT:** 
I've found out that location of my project (on disk "C" or on disk "D") makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem, just create a new project with different name following the instructions:

http://slickjuanito.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/setting-up-umbraco-development-environment-in-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: It's probably even better to use Umbraco 5 project templates that are available through nuget and VS extension manager:  http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/2/28/nuget-packages-and-visual-studio-templates.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a permissions problem. Did you install IIS after installing .NET framework 4? 
You could try running The 'aspnet_regiis -ir' command to re-install the framework, which should also reset file permissions for these folders.

Comment: It's useful, I'll keep it in mind, thank you! Now the issue is solved. See my answer above.